# APIリファレンス (/operators) での passwordパラメータフォーマットの記載について

Tags: soracom

https://dev.soracom.io/jp/docs/api/#!/Operator/create_operator

の新規operatorのinvitationメールを送るためのAPIについて、
passwordパラメータをsignup時に指定されている以下のフォーマット以外にすると、

```
Passwords must:
  - Be a minimum of 8 characters
  - Include at least one lowercase letter (a-z)
  - Include at least one uppercase letter (A-Z)
  - Include at least one number (0-9)
```

APIのレスポンスは HTTP Status Code == 400となり、
Response bodyは以下のものが返ってきます。

```
{
  "code": "AUM0010",
  "message": "Invalid password format."
}
```

できれば、なのですがAPI ドキュメントにも記載していただくと良いかな、と思います。m(_ _)m

Comment: 製品への要望などは公式のサポートへ連絡された方がよいかと思います。

Answer (score 0):

ご指摘ありがとうございます。そのとおりですね。
パスワードのフォーマットについて API リファレンスに記載するようにします。

Comment: ありがとうございますm(_ _)m